# Journey builder in Child business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is it possible to use Salesforce Data as an entry source of a journey in a child business unit? I tried but the contact didn't enter the journey.

Comment: What does the journey history show for the failed contact?

Comment: No history at all. Even though the contact meets the criteria, it doesn't go into the journey. When customers fill in our form, we will create contacts in SF. I want these contacts to go into the journey immediately.

Comment: Usually you also see if contacts aren't accepted for the journey even if they don't meet the criteria with a certain message. Is the Trigger visible in Sales/Service Cloud? Is the journey activated (there is no test mode for salesforce data events)?

Comment: It is active and no test mode. Contact evaluated shows 0.

Comment: Does your integration user in MC have access to the child BU? It is a prerequisite for entry event to work.

Comment: Thank you Luckas. Yes, our integration user has access to all the BU.

Comment: How much filtering are you doing on the entry event? To troubleshoot you might try to let everyone through, then use a decision split. This will at least tell you if you are actually getting users in your journey.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have learnt that I had to go to Marketing cloud tab from Sales Cloud> Configure Marketing cloud connect> Manage Business Unit. Now contacts go into the journey in Child BU. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you've answered the question in the comments. I'm posting it here with more information so it would be more clear to other persons running into this use case..

The answer is **YES**, it is possible to use Salesforce Data as an entry source of a journey in a child business unit.

But, you need to do two things:

1- Add child business unit to your API user on Marketing Cloud. Go to Setup > Users > Check your API user and click Manage Business Units > check your child business unit..

2- Go to Sales/Service Cloud > Configure Marketing Cloud > Manage Business Units > Check your child business unit.

You must add Business Units to your API user on Marketing Cloud first, otherwise, you will not see all Business units on step 2.